# Enabling replication for VM to Azure: Unable to install mobility service

Tags: azure

Attempting to replicate Vmware on-premises VM to Azure and getting this message:

ERROR ID: 78007
The requested operation did not complete.

PROVIDER ERROR: Provider error code: 95107

Provider error message: Enable protection failed with error code EP0858 as the service was unable to install mobility service on to the source machine (192.168.100.19).

Provider error possible causes: The user name or password provided to enable protection is incorrect or does not have sufficient (administrator) privileges to perform installation of mobility service.

Perhaps someone has seen this before and can point me in the right direction.

[image: Azure Replication Error]

Answer (score 1):

For Error Code 95107, Ensure that the user credentials provided for the source machine on the configuration server are correct.

You can go to the configuration server and select **Cspsconfigtool > Manage account.** Check the following [prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-install-mobility-service#install-mobility-service-by-push-installation-from-azure-site-recovery) to successfully finish the push installation.

References: [Error 95107 - Protection could not be enabled (EP0858)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-troubleshoot-push-install#error-95107---protection-could-not-be-enabled-ep0858)

Comment: Is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you.   After a good night's sleep the above information made more sense.  My brain works better in the morning.

Comment: Glad to hear that, good day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I used to install the mobility service manually.  I did use the link provided by Nancy above, and just in case that page gets moved or taken down for whatever reason, I want to post the solution here for others.

1. Sign in to your Azure configuration server / replication / site recovery server, and then open a command prompt window as an administrator.
2. Change the directory to this location:
   cd %ProgramData%\ASR\home\svsystems\bin
3. Generate a passphrase for the mobility service:
   genpassphrase.exe -v > MobSvc.passphrase

Store the passphrase in a secure location. You use the file during Mobility Service installation.

4. Copy the appropriate installer from here:

%ProgramData%\ASR\home\svsystems\pushinstallsvc\repository

5. Go to the VM you wish to replicate, and run the installer you copied.